# Is there a desgin pattern that would help to compare big amount of data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, design-patterns, ado.net

I need to compare particular content of 2 SQL tables located in different servers: Table1 and Table2.

I want to compare each row from Table1 against the whole content of Table2.

Comparison logic is kind of complicated so I want to apply a logical operator that I will wrinte in C#. So I don't want to do the comparison on the SQL query itself.

My concern is the size of the data I will work on will be around 200 MB.

I was thinking to load the data into a DataTable by using ADO.Net and do the comparison on the memory.

What would you recommend? Is there already a pattern like approach to compare massive data?

Comment: Are the two tables in the same database?

Comment: No they are in different Database-servers.

Comment: datareader would be the fastest way to read data

Comment: What do you mean "compare each row to all the rows in the other table".  What type of comparison, what result will you do. If you are just looking to see if a particular row exists in the other table then there are things that can be done to speed it up, but if you actually have to compare against every other row and do something per row, then that is just  a brute force nested loop.

Comment: You may prefer to use a stored procedure to retrieve data for datareader, which will cache the query in "execution plan". Thus, it will be much-much faster.

Comment: Temporarily writing 2-nd table into the same server where 1-st table is located, and doing your operation and truncating the copied table data - might be a good option.

Comment: Check out the SQL CRL answer from Pana...  The C# logic is run on the SQL server.  With two boxes you are still going to have network traffic between the two boxes.  If the the tables are different sizes then run the query on the box with the larger table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

200 MB should not be a problem. A .NET application can handle much more than that at once.

But even so, I would probably use a forward-only data reader for Table 1, just because there's no good reason not to, and that should reduce the amount of memory required. You can keep table 2 in memory with whatever structure you are accustomed to.

Comment: I agree.  I should have done something like this in my tool Data Comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two SqlDataReaders. They only have one row in memory at a time, are forward only, and extremely efficient. After getting the row back from the reader you can then compare the values. Here is an example.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx).

Comment: But where the query result is stored so that it does not re-execute the SQL query?

Comment: @pencil: The result is retrieved from the server in chunks.

Comment: @NiklasB. Thank you. You can see the explanation in the article as well.

Comment: @pencilCake, You may easily use a stored procedure which will cache the query in "execution plan".

Comment: he has to view every row in the second table multiple times, so forward-only will not work and cause him to re-run the query.

Comment: @JasonCoyne The idea is that the two tables are already the "same table" and so you sort them both properly in the query and iterate the second one forward appropriately when a PK match is found.

Comment: @Jason: You are correct. Maybe to read Table1 SqlDataReader might work while I have the content of Table2 in the memory as a DataTable... It will be big around 200 Mb as I say... How does it sound?

Comment: @mperrenoud03 : Same in terms of table definition but the content differs.

Comment: @pencilCake Again, if you aren't comparing the row on PK then that may be necessary so you can query the second one. However, if the two tables are the "same table" then you will be able to iterate the second every time you find a match, otherwise not.

Comment: Also, depending on what work is being done as a result of the comparison, if it takes much time, then datareaders would be a scalability issue, because they are holding open the connections to their database. Vs a datatable would be populated and then the connection closed immediately if the processing was of long duration

Answer (score 1):

The most scalable solution is to create SQLCLR functions to execute the comparisons you want.

You should probably avoid a row-by-row comparison at all costs. The network latency and delays due to round-tripping will result in extremely slow execution.

A quick&dirty solution is to extract the data to local files then do the comparison as you will pay the network tax only once. Unfortunately, you lose the speedup provided by database indexes and query optimizations.

A similar solution is to load all the data once in memory and then use indexing structures like dictionaries to provide additional speedup. This is probably doable as your data can fit in memory. You still pay the network tax only once but gain from faster execution.

The most scalable solution is to create [SQLCLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2e1fb36) code to create one or more functions that will perform the comparisons you want. This way you avoid the network tax altogether, avoid creating and optimizing your own structures in memory and can take advantage of indexes and optimizations.

Comment: He said they were in different databases, so SQLCLR won't work.

Comment: Why not? It will, in the same way that queries that target linked servers do. The UDFs will have to be deployed on all servers and the query should be written in a way that only a minimum of info has to be transferred to a single server for processing, but that holds for any distributed query

Answer (score 1):

These solutions may not be applicable, depending on the actual logic of the comparisons you are doing. Both solutions rely on sorting the data correctly

1) Binary search. - You can find the matching row in table 2 without scanning through all of table 2 by using a binary search, this will significantly reduce the number of comparisons

2) If you are looking for overlaps/matches/missing rows between the two tables, you can sort both tables in the same order. Then you can loop through the two tables simultaniously, keeping a pointer to the current row of each table. If table 1 is "ahead" of table 2, then you only increment the table 2 pointer until they are either equal, or table 2 is ahead. Then once table 2 is ahead, you start incrementing table 1 until it is ahead. etc. In this way you only have to loop through each record from each table one time, and you are guaranteed that there were no matches that you missed.

If table 1 and 2 match, then that is a match. while table 1 is ahead, then every row in table 2 is "missing" from table 1, and visa versa.

This solution would also work if you only need to take some action if the rows are in a certain range of each other or something.

3) If you have to actually do some action for every row in table 2 for every row in table 1, then its just two nested loops, and there is not much that you can do to optimize that other than make the comparison/work as efficient as possible. You could possibly multi-thread it though depending on what the work was and where your bottle-neck is.

Answer (score 0):

Can you stage the data to the same database using a quick ETL/SSIS job? This would allow you to do set operations which might be easier deal with. If not, I would agree with the recommendations for forward-only data reader with one table in memory

Answer (score 0):

A couple years ago I wrote a db table comparison tool, which is now an open-source project called [Data Comparisons](http://www.bucketsoft.com/data_comparisons/).

You can check out the [source code](http://datacomparisons.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) if you want.  There is a massive optimization you can make when the two tables you're comparing are on the same physical server, because you can write a SQL query to take care of this.  I called this the "Quick compare" method in Data Comparisons, and it's available whenever you're sharing the same connection string for both sides of the comparison.

When they're on two different servers, however, you have no choice but to pull the data into memory and compare the rows there.  Using SqlDataReaders would work.  However, it's complicated when you must know exactly what's different (what rows are missing from table A or table B, what rows are different, etc).  For that reason my method was to use DataTables, which are slower but at least they provide you with the necessary functionality.

Building this tool was a learning process for me.  There are probably opportunities for optimization with the in-memory comparison.  For example, loading the data into a Dictionary and doing your comparisons off of primary keys with Linq would probably be faster.  You could even try Parallel Linq and see if that helps.  And as Jeffrey L Whitledge mentioned, you might as well use a SqlDataReader for one of the tables while the other is stored in memory.